# Proof that exists a diffeomorphism $g:\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$, such that $∂(f∘g)/∂x$ $=0$ for any point of $\Bbb R^3$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$ such that $∂f/∂x$ + $∂f/∂y$ + $∂f/∂z$ $= 0$ for any point of $\Bbb R^3$. Proof that there exists a diffeomorphism $g:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$, such that $∂(f∘g)/∂x=0$ for any point of $\Bbb R^3$.

So, I was thinking to use $g$ linear. I tried to use $g(x,y,z)=(2x,2y,2z)$ because is one-to-one, differentiable and $g^{-1}$ is differentiable, but that doesn't work. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Shouldn't $f$ be a map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb R$?

Comment: **HINT**: Think about the chain rule. You're right to think about linear maps, but what possible change(s) of variables will turn the sum of the partial derivatives into a single partial derivative?

Comment: Sorry, $f:R^3->R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is a map to value in $\mathbb{R}$ than

$\frac{\partial (f\circ g)}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial  g_3}{\partial x} $

And so you can choose for example the linear map $g(x,y,z)=(x,x+y,x+z)$